# How to enable or allow user to manually enter the date in JQuery datepicker field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am building a webportal, where some of the text fields are date picker. When we click on datepicker, a date selection tab appears to select the date, but the field is not allowing to enter the date manually.

I require a way where the user can get both the option, select from date pop up or can enter manually.

Here is a simple code for same:

```
<input id="ae_point_2_date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="fieldValue form-element hasDatepicker datePick datepickernew mandt">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this jquery example https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/default.html
you can enter the date manually like this

```
07/12/1993
```

You can find more information here -> https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

I used this myself and I highly recommend it.